# auto increment according to same column values

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table like this:

```
| id |    item    |
+----+------------+ 
|    | item1      |
|    | item1      |
|    | item2      |
|    | item2      |
|    | item2      |
|    | item3      |
|    | item3      |
```

i need to add column id by auto increment like this:

```
| id |    item    |
+----+------------+ 
| 1  | item1      |
| 2  | item1      |
| 1  | item2      |
| 2  | item2      |
| 3  | item2      |
| 1  | item3      |
| 2  | item3      |
```

each of the same values ​​in the item column will result in a number sequence according to the number of item rows. and if the row has been deleted, it should still be in order..

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id INT null, val VARCHAR(10) null)

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES 
    (NULL,'xxx1'),
    (NULL,'xxx1'),
    (NULL,'xxx2'),
    (NULL,'xxx2'),
    (NULL,'xxx2'),
    (NULL,'xxx3')

SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY val) AS id, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by val ORDER BY val) AS sub_id, 
    val FROM @t
```

[image]